# Sqlite foreign key does not work

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I read all the previous issues with the foreign keys. I did all the possible configurations but I can not enforce it to work.
I can insert to the nodes table even if I don't have any record in the types table. But as I know the foreign key constraint should not allow this to happen.

```
CREATE TABLE nodes(
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
ver int NOT NULL,
lock int NOT NULL,
title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
typeid int NOT NULL REFERENCES types(id),
desc text NOT NULL,
CHECK(trim(id) <> '' AND trim(ver) <> '' AND trim(lock) <>'' AND trim(title) 
<> '' AND trim(typeid) <> '' AND trim(desc) <> '' )
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "types" 
("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"name" TEXT NOT NULL )
```

SQLite 3.19.3

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
foreign_keys
------------
1

sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys_list;
sqlite>
```

I don't know why `PRAGMA foreign_keys_list` answer is empty.

---

It is solved because I used `s` in my command
Correct : `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(nodes)`

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_list(nodes);
id          seq         table       from        to          on_update   on_delete   match
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------    ------------
0           0           types       typeid      id          NO ACTION   NO ACTION   NONE
```

Comment: What did googling 'sqlite pragma foreign key list' get you?

Comment: It should show me the foreign keys but the result is empty. I define the foreign key in my nodes table.

Comment: My error, I misread.

Comment: I fixed your code/table formatting (again), please look at the formated version before you save. You can't format a table in comments. But please put clarifications in your answer anyway. Also, if you have new question, please ask in a new post. Google your error message. Don't forget about [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `PRAGMA foreign_key_list(table-name);`

Comment: I check it also. the result is empty. I think it should show something for
    PRAGMA foreign_key_list(nodes);

Answer (score 1):

Remove that `s` after `key` — SQlite won't warn you if you made a typo and simply returns nothing.

Comment: You are right. But why I can insert anything into my nodes table even I don't have any data in types table? this my question. Why don't I get any error?