# Column names of pragma_foreign_key_list

Tags: sqlite

What are the column names of the resulting table of `pragma_foreign_key_list` [(doc)](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_list) in sqlite? Or even better, how can I find out about them myself (as I also want to use other pragmas)?

For clarification: I want to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_foreign_key_list('SomeTable');
```

in order to see the foreign keys of a table. However I will have to read specific columns of that table and maybe I don't want to select all of them in the first place. For some reason the table I receive does not look like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45336445/5909613) but has no column headline.

Comment: If you're working from the sqlite3 command line shell, make sure you've executed the `.headers on` command first to see the names of columns in results. (I have that in my `~/.sqliterc` so it's always in effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that example in your second link:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_key_list(nodes);
id          seq         table       from        to          on_update   on_delete   match
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------    ------------
0           0           types       typeid      id          NO ACTION   NO ACTION   NONE
```

- `id` and `seq` - each row the pragma returns refers to a single column, but foreign keys can be composite ones with multiple columns. `id` refers to the Nth key, and `seq` to the Nth column in that key. So a table with a single FK on two columns would have rows with id = 0 seq = 0 and id = 0 seq = 1.
- `table` and `to` - The parent table and column in it the FK refers to. `types.id` in this case.
- `from` the column in the child table that has the FK constraint. `nodes.typeid` in this case.
- `on_update` and `on_delete` - the actions taken when the referenced foreign key is updated or deleted.
- `match` - A SQL92 feature for foreign key actions related to null values that sqlite doesn't implement but does accept syntax-wise in case it ever does add support.